# Does Google Apps Migration work for merging 2 email accounts within the same Google Apps domain?

Tags: google-workspace, migration, google-apps-for-work

Suppose my Google Apps domain is `example.com` and there are 2 user accounts: `bob@example.com` and `bob2@example.com`.  Both containing on the order of 10 GB of email.

The goal is to copy all email from `bob2@example.com` into `bob@example.com`, such that eventually `bob@example.com` contains the union.  Then `bob2@example.com` can be deleted, and I save on Google Apps subscription.

Is this possible using the Google Apps Migration tool (via the Admin Panel)?
When I tried it, first, I give the credentials of the source account, then I am taken to a complete list of all my user accounts.  And it is not clear what's what.

Is Google Apps Migrations not designed for my use case? What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1):

Depends...

The migration panel is built to retrieve all emails from inboxes on other platforms, you don't state if your source is outside Google Apps and I haven't heard from someone using the tool inside Google itself, so I can't be sure of the answer if that is your case.

Nevertheless, that tool works making a POP or IMAP connection to any common email inbox that has that possibilities (almost all have), so it should work in almost any case.

You could give it a try... For any case I would prefer to simply do the work manually setting a POP account to be retrieved from the existing final Google Apps account. That's the procedure we use when doing backups and similar needs.